# Reindexing catalog_product_flat causes Mysql error 1117 Too many colums

Tags: magento2, database, flat-indexer

We are building a **Magento 2** website with **60K products** and 1 website, 64 stores with 64 store views.

Now we try to enable `catalog_product_flat` and `catalog_category_flat` (this works fine) for production mode. When we run:

`php current/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_flat`

it gives the following error:

`General error: 1117 Too many columns` (see below for the complete error)

We have about 2585 attributes in the total website, but for some reason we can't assign 10 attributes for store 1 and the next 20 for store 2. Instead all of the 2585 attributes are assigned to each store. Could somebody explain how this works in big Magento 2 stores with millions of products?

Server setup:

- Apache version: Apache/2.4.29
- PHP version: 7.1.10
- MySQL version: 10.1.26-MariaDB
- Magento2 version 2.2.1

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1117 Too many columns, query was:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text_tmp_indexer` (
      `entity_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Entity_id' ,
      `type_id` text NULL COMMENT 'Type_id' ,
      `attribute_set_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Attribute_set_id' ,
      `description` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Description' ,
      `short_description` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Short_description' ,
      `meta_keyword` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Meta_keyword' ,
      .................................
      `reserve_onderdeel` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Reserve_onderdeel' ,
      `reparatieset` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Reparatieset' ,
      `overdraagbaar_vermogen` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Overdraagbaar_vermogen'
) COMMENT='catalog_product_entity_text_tmp_indexer' ENGINE=innodb charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Have you ever find solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not support more than 64 attributes in the flat index due to [MySql limitation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html) of maximum secondary indexes.

Also, Magento 2.2 has improvement related to support a store with a big number of attributes, so I believe you can disable flat indexer in your case.